# Find a function f(n) such that T(n) is $\Theta(n \cdot log(n)) $

Tags: analysis, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

Find a function f(n) such that $ T(n)=16 \cdot T(\frac{n}{4}) + f(n) = \Theta(n \cdot log(n)) $

Also, another section of the question is where $T(n) = \Theta(n^{2})$

I've tried using the master method in reverse, but have failed to accomplish anything.

Any ideas?

**EDIT!**
My apologies! I have just discovered that some of the questions were meant to be unsolvable, the matter is understood then. Thank you all for your guidelines!

Comment: Unless there is some typo in what you wrote (or I made a mistake in checking it),  "the Master Theorem in reverse" does not look like it could help here. Note that you have $a=16$ and $b=4$, so that $\log_b a = 2$. Looking through cases [$1$ and $2$ of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2), they will not give you what you want:
- Case 1 would give you $\Theta(n^c)$ for some $c< 2$
- Case 2 would give you $\Theta(n^2 \log^k n)$ for some $k \geq 0$
- Case 2 would give you $\Theta(f(n))$ but for $f(n) = \Omega(n^{2+\epsilon})$, so eventually $T(n) = \omega(n\log n)$.

Comment: Are you certain it shouldn't read $n^2\log n $?

Comment: Very certain about it sir.
And the reason being another question that asks about $n^{2}log(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible. Notice that under the (very natural) assumption that $f\geq 0$, then  you get
$$
T(n) \geq 16 T\!\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)
$$
so that $T(n) \geq T^\prime(n)$ where $T^\prime$ is defined by the same initial conditions as $T$ and satisfies
$$
T^\prime(n)  = 16 T^\prime\!\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)
$$
Not, solving this last recurrence (e.g., via the Master theorem, although in this case it is overkill) results in $T^\prime(n) = \Theta(n^2)$. Therefore, we get $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$, ruling out the possibility that $T(n) = \Theta(n\log n)$.

---

Note that getting $T(n) = \Theta(n^2\log n)$, however, *is* possible, so it may have been a typo.